# How can I scrape inside a div tag with node.js?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

I am looking at something like this:

```
<div class="f00" thing="??" other-thing="???"></div>
```

I am trying to get ?? and ??? and I am totally stuck. I tried getting all the html that is inside the div that wraps around this but there is a ton of other code on the same level as this so I just get a wall of html that I don't need. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package you are looking for is `htmlparser2`. I specifically like to use it with `cheerio`, which is a sort of wrapper around it and supplies jQuery-like functionality.

You would do something like:

```
$ = cheerio.load(yourHtml);
thing = $('.foo').attr('thing');
otherThing = $('.foo').attr('other-thing');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) with node.js, it makes it a lot easier to work with DOM.
With it you can do stuff like...

```
var thing = $('.f00').attr('thing');
var other-thing = $('.f00').attr('other-thing');
```

Have a look at jQuery api to get a better idea of what it can do... it can do a great deal.

**EDIT**
you need jQuery installed.

```
npm install jquery
```

For instructions how to get npm look [here](https://npmjs.org/)
For more information about node-jquery have a look at the [github repository](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery)

*Hope it helps :)*